# How to make vba file delete itself

Tags: windows, vba, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to make a program delete itself and I'm using a separate batch file to do it. I'm using this code:

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", 
    "/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 1 & Del " + Application.ExecutablePath)
Application.Exit()
```

But it can't delete files with a space in the name. How do I surround `Application.ExecutablePath` with "" so it looks like "FileName" in the end?

Comment: In batch files if a file has spaces in it, you have to surround it with "quotes".

Comment: Nevermind I used the code quote = Chr(34)
        applicationPath = fso.GetFileName(Application.ExecutablePath)
        Process.Start(Desktop3 & "\UPDATE.exe")
        Process.Start("cmd.exe",
    "/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 1 & Del " + quote & applicationPath & quote)
        Application.Exit()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, I used this code:

```
Dim applicationPath As String
Dim quote As String
quote = Chr(34)
applicationPath = fso.GetFileName(Application.ExecutablePath)
Process.Start("cmd.exe",
    "/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 1 & Del " + quote & applicationPath & quote)
Application.Exit()
```

There is a lot of extra code for problem solving. So I cut It down to this:

```
Dim quote As String
quote = Chr(34)
Process.Start("cmd.exe",
    "/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 1 & Del " + quote & Application.ExecutablePath & quote)
Application.Exit()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm glad you figured out the issue.  Please remember to mark your answer as the accepted solution!